# What is the best way to ensure a reliable path in Python?

Tags: python, path, filesystems

I'm a bit puzzled by the way paths are handled in Python. Using common constructs line "~" or "." or "..", I often run into cases where a path is not recognized as valid or existing, especially if I pass the path on as an argument to a shell command; but *all* of my problems go away if I *always* do something like:

```
some_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(some_path))
```

Is this a common — or perhaps even required — idiom, or am I just reinventing the wheel? Should I really expect that wherever I have `some_path`, I should have the above code before passing it to any (or at least most) functions that do anything with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most things you can call will expect path that has been run through that idiom. When you use paths like that in the shell (eg, when you do something like `cat ~raxacoricofallapatorius/foo.txt`), it is *the shell itself* - rather than `cat` or any other program you might run - that does the path normalisation.

You can verify this trivially - eg,

```
lvc@tiamat:~/Projects$ echo ~
/home/lvc
```

So this does mean that if you expect to get a path with those kinds of variables as input, you will need to do the preprocessing yourself. The alternative is to run the commands through a shell, and be ready to deal with all the problems *that* brings.

However, at least on unix-like systems (Windows may or may not behave the same way), you *don't* need to do this for `.` and `..` - these are understood by the system calls, and the shell does not transform them - so, eg:

```
lvc@tiamat:~/Projects$ file ..
..: directory
lvc@tiamat:~/Projects$ file ~
/home/lvc: directory
```

Notice that `file` sees `..` unchanged, but sees the expanded form of `~`.

This means that if all you want is paths that will work directly in external programs, passing it through `expanduser` and possibly `expandvars` is sufficient. You will want to call `abspath` primarily if the program you are calling out to will run in a different working directory than yours.

Comment: Does it matter which function is invoked first — `expandvars` or `expanduser`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you need an absolute path with `$HOME` resolved, you'll have to do that.

It should be easy enough to write a short helper function, if you require this functionality regularly. There are also path helper libraries available, like these:

- https://github.com/jaraco/path.py
- https://github.com/xando/python-shelltools

Answer (score -1):

It's generally a good idea.  os.path.abspath will resolve relative paths like ., .., and ~.  If you want your code to be portable across OSes, you should be using os.path instead of defining your own path handling, if you can - os.path always points to the correct path module for the OS you are on.  If you try define your own path functions, you lose the built-in cross platform behavior of os.path.